# Finding distance from Point to LineString in meters using Python

Tags: python, distance, geopandas, shapely, linestring

I have tried this following method to find distance but it is giving me distance like 0.12. I don't know what that 0.12 is meant and I want the distance to be in **meters** or kilometers.

```
line.distance(point)
```

Here line is the line string and point is (88.193,22.233).

Comment: Some more details are necessary, but it's quite likely that the units are Cartesian degrees (which are worse than useless)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use GeoPandas, you can use PyProj directly. See [Getting Started | Geodesic Calculations](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#geodesic-calculations).

```py
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import nearest_points


geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")  # Your data may be from a different Geod.

line = LineString(((0, 0), (0, 1)))
point = Point(1, 1)

distance = geod.geometry_length(LineString(nearest_points(line, point)))
# distance is 111302.64933943082 meters
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance you get could be in degrees, it depends on the coordinate system you use. Project to a CRS in meters:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

linedf = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/linewgs84.shp')
pointdf = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/pointwgs84.shp')

linedf.geometry.to_crs(epsg=32636).distance(pointdf.to_crs(epsg=32636))
```

I drew a line and point over Egypt so I use [WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N](https://epsg.io/32636). You're in Bangladesh? Then you can try [EPSG:32646](https://epsg.io/32646)

Comment: It is showing an error that 'LineString' has no attribute 'geometry'. I am using that World 1984 coordinate system